# shell script, read is not waiting with ssh

Tags: command-line, scripts

Hi all I am new to shell scripting and please help me in this situation.
I have created a shell script named ./remote1 which looks like below.

> # ./remote1 file
>   ssh username@x.x.x.x  'bash -s' < ./createdir

Here 'createdir' is another file i had created which is given below

> # ./createdir file
>   echo "give directory name"
>   read name
>   mkdir ~/$name

If I run the ./createdir alone in my machine, it will execute without any problem.

If I execute ./remote1, it will not wait for input the data for the 'read' command.Please anyone could help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026580/shell-script-read-command-is-not-waiting-along-with-ssh

Comment: is createdir file present in the remote computer(x.x.x.x)?

Comment: This works: `ssh host "bash -c 'read data; echo \$data'"` - I suspect using `bash -s` does something like block any builtins (eg, `read`) from using `STDIN`, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to exec the command via ssh on another machine. Bute there is no one who could give an answer to the read command.

Try to read the name on the local machine and put in a variable like:

remote1:

```
echo "give directory name"
read name
ssh username@x.x.x.x mkdir ~/$name
```

I cant test it now, but I think this will execute the mkdir on the remote machine directly vis ssh, without anoter script on it.